# How to get full substring in a string?

Tags: php, strpos

I have variable `$mystring = "abc+adb"` and I am trying to find ab in the `$mystring`. I want to throw a message which say ab does not exist in `$mystring`, but the following code keeps picking ab from abc, I want ab to be treated as a standalone substring;

```
$mystring = 'abc+adb';
$findme   = 'bc';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} 
else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Tell us how it should be.

Comment: I want `ab` to be treated as a standalone substring? what does that mean anyway?

Comment: Oh sorry, I did a mistake its not ab its bc which is in $findme variable. What i want is when user enters bc, the code should throw an error, saying bc is not available,  rather than matching  bc from 'abc' in $mystring. So, bc should be treated as a substring on its own just like abc and adb in $mystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use strpos for that.

[strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos) - Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

You can use a regular expression to do that. By no means am I a master of regular expression, but a simple example that meets your immediate need is:

```
preg_match('/\bab\b/', $mystring);
```

The [preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) function will return 1 if successful, 0 if no matches found or false in if there was an error.

```
$mystring = 'abc+adb';
$findme   = 'bc';
if ( preg_match('/\b'  . $findme . '\b/',$mystring) ) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```